# Run an event only once in NodeJS but use the data multiple times

Tags: node.js, variables, events

So I have written this code :

```
     manager.getInventoryContents(730, 2, true, (err,inventory,currencies) => {
  if (err){
    console.log(err)
  } else {
    console.log("Create order for : " + orderitemname.length + " items.")
    var otn = orderitemname.length -1;
    while (otn !== -1) {
      var li= inventory.length - 1;
      while (li !== -1){
        if (inventory[li].market_name === orderitemname[otn]){
          console.log("Add item to trade " + orderitemname[otn]);
          li = li -1;
          otn = otn -1;
        } else {
          console.log("ERR !!! ITEM NOT IN INVENTORY !!! " + orderitemname[otn]);
          //Change Order Status To Failed !!
          n = n-1;
          otn = -1;
          li = -1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

So what is happening is that the process is calling this event multiple times (since it is in a while loop), and the node module is ignoreing it saying :

```
Error: The request is a duplicate and the action has already occurred in the past, ignored this time
```

So is there a way I can just call the event once, save it to a variable or something and then use the data multiple time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap everything in a new context and initiate whatever variable you need there. Then, the variable will be accessible from within your callback function.

Something like this:

```
(() => {
    let ctx_data = 0;
    manager.getInventoryContents(730, 2, true, (err,inventory,currencies) => {
        console.log(++ctx_data);
    });
})();
```

Comment: Yeah, I actually figured it out, what I did was I called the event once and set the callbacks to variables, then used those variables to read data from instead of calling the event again and again. Also, I don't get why you have added that ctx_data, all I did was call the event and used variables to refer to the callbacks.

Comment: That's what you asked.